# Yahoo yql rate limit

Tags: yahoo, yql

I have been reading alot about YQL and the Rate Limits however Im a little stuck on.

These are the figures I have found

Per application limit (identified by your Access Key): 100,000 calls per day.

Per IP limits: /v1/public/*: 1,000 calls per hour; /v1/yql/*: 10,000 calls per hour.

My question is how will yahoo track the application and its limit ?

Also if I want to use the YQL as my data source do I need to register my application or can I use curl to run the queries without any problems ?

Sorry if I have got it wrong but some help would be great

Sorry if its a noob question

Answer (score 0):

For registering your application see the "How to I get started" section here:
http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/

Without an API key the "per IP limit" applies which, as the name says, is tracked by the IP from which the requests are coming.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

To up the limit, you have to use some library which implements OAuth, see [Any .NET examples for Yahoo Query Language (YQL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251874/any-net-examples-for-yahoo-query-language-yql)