# Any .NET examples for Yahoo Query Language (YQL)?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, yql

I'd like to make some simple calls to [Yahoo Query Language (YQL)](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/). Has anyone implemented this in .NET?

Here is the query I'd like to make from .NET:

```
select MarketCapitalization 
from yahoo.finance.quotes 
where symbol 
  in ("YHOO","AAPL","GOOG","MSFT","unknown")
```

**Update**

Everything is working 100%, thanks @fernaramburu.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. There two good examples that are actually working because I just tested some hours ago...

http://jarloo.com/get-yahoo-finance-api-data-via-yql/

and

http://jarloo.com/code/get-historical-stock-data/

Hope this help! It helps me a lot!

Answer (score 6):

Not really an example, but a complete .NET library is [Yahoo! Finance Managed](http://code.google.com/p/yahoo-finance-managed/).

A description for using the lib can you find [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/YahooFinance_Managed.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

> To access the YQL Web Service, a Web application can call HTTP GET, passing the YQL statement as a URL parameter...

Then [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.webrequest%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) would be your friend.
You can find tons of information how to make GET calls to a webservice on the net.

Or are you talking about a LINQ-Provider?

Comment: I had a look for a YQL LINQ provider, there doesn't seem to be one, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

There is a complete example (with downloadable .NET source code) here:

http://andy.edinborough.org/C-OAuth-Implementation/

This example implements OAuth to let you take advantage of the higher usage limit of 100,000 requests / day and 10,000 requests / hour.

To create an OAuth key, see [So, you want to use some Yahoo! APIs](https://developer.apps.yahoo.com/dashboard/createKey.html).

The code won't work without a minor change: replace the query for pizza with "show tables".

**Update:**

YQL didn't work with without appending the following string to the query:

```
&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env
```

The full query string is:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%22MSFT%22%29&diagnostics=true&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env
```

To obtain a full query URL from a YQL query:

- Browse to the [Yahoo YQL query console](http://y.ahoo.it/H39SRFQR).
- Create a query, e.g. `select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ("MSFT")`
- On the base of the page, there is a section under "The Rest Query". Copy this. This URL will work in any browser (or any desktop app that uses YQL).
- Modify the [C# source](http://andy.edinborough.org/C-OAuth-Implementation/) to append the string `&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env` to the url within the two overloaded `QueryYahoo` functions.