# yql query doesn't work

Tags: ajax, yahoo, yql

i'm using yql for cross domain ajax
(using cross domain mod for jquery,
https://github.com/padolsey/jquery.fn/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax)

it has worked till few days ago but suddenly doesn't work.

here's my simple query:
select * from html where url="mysite" and xpath

even samples are not working now on https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/

what happened? or is it my bad? anyone same as me?

Comment: What is the nature of the error beyond "it doesn't work"?

Comment: Apparently there is a hit limit (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407937/yahoo-yql-rate-limit?rq=1) but it can't be applied to the Yahoo's samples page itself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened to me too! Is working intermittently...

This is another online demo: http://icant.co.uk/articles/crossdomain-ajax-with-jquery/error-handling.html. The code used to work. Now is matter of luck.

I replaced all my scripts with CORS (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/), but it needs to modify the requested URL header and only is possible if you request a URL of your own server.

Comment: i've changed all the codes .. just get html through server side.. anyway thx! im relieved for your comment